# How to Test Void method which contains void method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

I am using PowerMockito. I would like to test the following code.

```
class Foo{
    void outerVoid(){
        innerVoid(); // method of another class
    }
}
```

How can I test OuterVoid() without invoking the innerVoid()?

The innerVoid() contains database related objects so it should not be called, or it will become an integration test.

Comment: What assertions are you trying to validate? Typically you would mock the class that implements `innerVoid()` using an interface that the exposes.

Comment: Ryan,No assertions are checked cause there are no return values so i can't make an assertion about it.
Yup, i did mock the class using an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by refactoring your code if possible.

Create an interface `Bar`.

```
interface Bar {
    void innerVoid();
}
```

Now use the design pattern [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to inject an implementation of this interface with the `innerVoid()` method into your `Foo` class.

```
class Foo {
    Bar bar;

    Bar getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }

    void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    void outerVoid() {
        this.bar.innerVoid();
    }
}
```

Now you can mock the `Bar` class all you want.

```
Bar mockBar = createMockBar(...); // create a mock implementation of Bar
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setBar(mockBar);
... continue testing ...
```

Comment: also i forgot to mention that the setter method is called inside the outerVoid() so if i called outerVoid() it will again set the instance to concrete.

Comment: Which/what setter method?  If it's the setter for a `Bar` implementation, then... well, can the `Foo` class be refactored to allow for the kind of dependency injection I'm suggesting?

Comment: yes its for Bar.since setBar is called inside the outerVoid() our mockBar instance is lost.

Comment: That's why you would refactor the code so that outerVoid() was no longer responsible for calling setBar().  That's the principle of Dependency Injection.  It makes your code less tightly coupled.  The reason you're having trouble testing is because your code is too tightly coupled.

Comment: Agreed, DI does make things easier and testing them is real charm.But the code is not mine and i refactored it to include DI,It got rejected. :(

Comment: I don't know what to tell you then.  It's a perfectly valid technique, and one used heavily the Spring, a powerful library used in a lot of Java applications.

Comment: Marvo, The solution is absolutely right and viable i did as you said...its working and also tried to convince my senior but a checked code so i had to revert my changes...the Test Passed. Thanks :)